# VS2012 Using C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120) Underlines False Errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded and installed [Microsoft's pre-release C++ compiler for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515). My project's Platform Toolset for all configurations is set to: "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012)".

This allows my project to use the new C++11 features Microsoft implemented in their pre-release. Code using the new features compiles and runs perfectly fine, but I still get red underline squiggles as if my code has errors.

So far my best option is to entirely disable "C/C++ Squiggles". Is there some way I can make Visual Studio 2012 realize I am compiling with v120, and squiggle accordingly?

## Example

The following code runs as expected:

```
int values[] {4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

for(int i : values)
{
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

It produces the output:

> 4 3 2 1 0

However, Visual Studio 2012 underlines the first *values* in squiggly red, with the tooltip:

> *int values[]* 
>   *Error: incomplete type is not allowed*

Comment: IMO squiggles are not for C++ programmers, and should be disabled! IntelliSense errors does nothing, than just increasing the "Errors" count.

Answer (score 8):

You're not compiling with v120. You're compiling with v120 CTP. CTP stands for "Community Technology *Preview*", and part of the "Preview" bit is that Intellisense does not recognize any of the new constructs. This behaviour is effectively by design for the CTP and will not be fixed and has no workaround.

You will have to wait for Microsoft to finish bugfixing the CTP and release it as a proper update, which will presumably contain Intellisense support for the new features.

Comment: Yeah, I just changed that. Seems odd to me, but hey. The point is still quite valid.

Comment: Yeah, and specifically, the CTP contains *only* the compiler update and `<initializer_list>`, nothing else.

Comment: That's a load of my mind, I've tried so many C++11 features and gave up because of the squiggles. Now I know to try and compile it too.

Comment: @Puppy Is there any link to download the official c++11 for visual studio 2012? I can only find the CTP version on google. Thanks in advance!